# Происхождение слова «информатика»

Tags: этимология, история

Какова этимология «информатики»? Каков «возраст» этого слова?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: @Alex_ander спасибо, я уже читал Википедию. Мне хотелось бы узнать этимологию этого слово (как оно образовано).

Comment: Происходит это слово от двух французских слов: information — информация и automatioque — автоматика.

Comment: **Уважаемые участники, комментарии не предназначены для ответов. Пожалуйста, используйте специальную форму.**

Answer (score 1):

Слово "информатика" достаточно молодое и было предложено для использования в 1962 году Филиппом Дрейфусом. Происходит от двух французских слов:
***information*** (информация) + ***automatioque*** (автоматика) = ***informatique.***

Впервые же термин «информатика» (нем. *informatik*) был введен Карлом Штейнбухом в 1957 году для обозначения технической области, которая занималась автоматизированной обработкой информации при помощи электронных вычислительных машин.

Название науки *информатика* (англ. *informatics*), конечно, имеет прямую связь со словом *информация*, заимствованным из польского языка довольно давно, еще в Петровскую эпоху. Слово *информация* по своему происхождению является латинизмом.
*Informatio* в переводе значит "осведомление, просвещение".

---

Несмотря на то, что информатика как наука появилась относительно недавно, её происхождение следует связывать с работами Лейбница по построению первой вычислительной машины и разработке универсального (философского) исчисления.

[Го́тфрид Ви́льгельм Ле́йбниц, 21 июня (1 июля) 1646 — 14 ноября 1716) — саксонский философ, логик, математик, механик, физик, юрист, историк, дипломат, изобретатель и языковед. Основатель и первый президент Берлинской Академии наук, иностранный член Французской Академии наук.
Лейбниц, независимо от Ньютона, создал математический анализ — дифференциальное и интегральное исчисления, основанные на бесконечно малых; создал комбинаторику как науку; заложил основы математической логики; описал двоичную систему счисления с цифрами 0 и 1.]

*Первым в мире программистом была женщина – англичанка Ада Лавлэйс.* В середине 19 века она составила план операций для прообраза современной ЭВМ — аналитической машины Чарльза Беббиджа, с помощью которых можно было решить уравнение Бернулли, выражающее закон сохранения энергии движущейся жидкости.

Первый факультет информатики был основан в 1962 году в университете Пёрдью (*Purdue University*).
Высшей наградой за заслуги в области информатики является премия Тьюринга.

---

Получается, что слову *информация* — около трёхсот лет, в течение которых науки и технологии  развивались, готовя появление нового слова — *информатика.*